# Phrase for Knowing Everything About Someone

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm new to this awesome site! There is a popular saying that, in a conversation, one is sarcastically telling someone they know everything about another that begins with I know "your rank, serial number and ?" I cant remember what the third descriptive word is. Can you help? It comes from the military.

Comment: As #MRS30 said, it's "name, rank, and serial number".  However, I think this refers to knowing very little about a person.  In the movies, at least, it's all that a POW must tell his captors.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes, I am way off base here. My apologies to anyone I may have upset with respect to the military.

Comment: @LisaBri - No need to apologize -- I can't imagine anyone would take offense.  //  By the way, if you venture out into googling, you'll find you can figure out this sort of thing pretty quickly!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for "***Name***, rank and serial number"

See [convention III](https://www.icrc.org/applic/ihl/ihl.nsf/1595a804df7efd6bc125641400640d89/6fef854a3517b75ac125641e004a9e68?OpenDocument) of [the Geneva Conventions](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/geneva_conventions)

> **About Convention III:** One of the treaties created during the 1949 Convention, this defined what a Prisoner of War was, and accorded them
>   proper and humane treatment as specified by the first Convention.
>   Specifically, it required POWs to give only their name, rank, and
>   serial number to their captors. Nations party to the Convention may
>   not use torture to extract information from POWs.